# Power BI: Split Column by String from other column

Tags: split, powerbi, powerquery, delimiter

The Situation:

I have an column which contains information which needs to be extracted. Here is some example content:

| Row | Content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CompanyName1 OrderNumber1 SomeUnimportantStuf1 |
| 2 | CompanyName2 CompanySurname2 OrderNumber2 SomeUnimportantStuff2 |
| 3 | CompanyName3 CompanySurname3 CompanyAddition3 OrderNumber_ABC3 SomeUnimportantStuff3 SomeMoreUnimportantStuff3 |

So basically The Company Name (containing from 0 up to 3 spaces), an order number and some unneccesary information at the end.

I need to **extract** the **OrderNumber**. The Problems:

- Company names varies from one-word up to three-words
- No unique separators like comma
- The **OrderNumber** hasn't always the same length and sometimes an suffix like "_v3" or even more (but is has no space - so basically it's always the longest word in each cell)

What I've succesfully done so far:

- **Extracted** the **CompanyName** in an new column "CompanyName"

And this is the point where I'm stuck. For my understanding the easiest way would be:

- **Split** the column "**Content**" by the Delimiter in "**CompanyName**"
  Since the **OrderNumber** has no space within itself, i could split the column again and have the **OrderNumber** standing alone.

Another idea is to search for the **longest word** in the column "**Content**" and extract it. But I was unable to find any solution for that either.

Is there anyone who can give me an helpful hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the longest word in a string:

- split the string
- get length of each split
- get maximum length
- match max length to position
- return word at that position

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Content", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
        Text.Split([Content]," "){
            List.PositionOf(
                List.Transform(
                    Text.Split([Content]," "), 
                        each Text.Length(_)),
                                List.Max(
                                    List.Transform(
                                        Text.Split([Content]," "), 
                                            each Text.Length(_))))})
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

***Edit: M Code rewritten to better show algorithm***
*not sure if it is more or less efficient, but it is easier to understand*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Content", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
        let 
          wordList = Text.Split([Content]," "),
          lengthList = List.Transform(wordList, each Text.Length(_)),
          lengthLongestWord = List.Max(lengthList),
          positionLongestWord = List.PositionOf(lengthList,lengthLongestWord),
          longestWord = wordList{positionLongestWord}
        in 
          longestWord)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Hey @Ron Rosenfeld! 
Many thanks for your code - it works like an charm!

After checking the results I've figured out, there are a few entries, where the CompanyName is longer than the OrderNumber. But this is an minor problem and can be fixed manually. The main part is done with this solution and I thank you very much!

Comment: @DerKamiKatze Depending on your data set, perhaps, before applying this algorithm, **1.** Remove leading articles (`a,and,the,...` only if they are the first word). **2.** Split by space -- left-most only, then delete that column.  That might remove that part of the company name that is very long. And hopefully none of the company names are the same as an article.